# Show that the map is a linear functional and determine the dimension of the quotient space $V/ker(y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, solution-verification

During an exam I was given the following task:
Consider the vector space
$$V:=\{p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\  |\ p \text { has degree at most } 3\}$$
Show that the map
$$y(p)=p(0),\quad V\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$$

is a linear functional and determine the dimension of the quotient space $V/ker(y)$.
I argued that:
$$y\left(\gamma_{1} p_{1}+\gamma_{2} p_{2}\right)=p(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \alpha_{i} 0^{i}=0$$
and
$$\gamma_{1} y\left(p_{1}\right)+\gamma_{2} y\left(p_{2}\right)=\gamma_{1} p(0)+\gamma_{2} p(0)=\gamma_{1} \sum_{i}^{n} \alpha_{i} 0^{i}+\gamma_{2} \sum_{i}^{n} \alpha_{i} 0^{i}=0$$
However, I am not sure if this is correct, because what is $0^0$?
To determine the dimension of $V/ker(y)$, I argued that $y$ is the zero map with dimension $0$ and that the dimension of a polynomial of degree at most $3$ is $4$, and therefore that the dimension of $V/ker(y)$ is
$$\operatorname{dim} V-\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker} y)=4-0=4$$

Will someone tell me if I messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such expressions, $0^0$ is defined to be $1$.

Clearly $y$ is NOT the zero map. For example, the polynomial $1 \in V$ gets mapped to $1$. Also $X+1$ gets mapped to $1$.

By the isomorphism theorem, we have $$V/\ker y \cong y(V)= \mathbb{Q}$$

and thus $\dim_\mathbb{Q}(V/\ker y) = 1$.

Comment: Well, that's sad. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Also if $y$ was the zero map then $\ker y = V$ so you should end up with dimension 0. You made a mistake in a mistake :/

Comment: Why is the dimension of $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}[x] | p \text { has degree at most } 3\}$ not $4$?

Comment: It is $4$. I never said it wasn't.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was calculting the dimension of $V/y$. Oh my, the mistakes you can make when being stressed.

Comment: I know. Stuf happens! Take care!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

You are supposed to check that, if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in\Bbb Q$ and $p_1,p_2\in V$, then $y(\gamma_1p_1+\gamma_2p_2)=\gamma_1y(p_1)+\gamma_2y(p_2)$. However, you wrote that $y(\gamma_1p_1+\gamma_2p_2)=p(0)$, without saying what $p$ is. If$$p_1(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2+\alpha_3x^3\text{ and }p_2(x)=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2+\beta_3x^3,$$then both $y(\gamma_1p_1+\gamma_2p_2)$ and $\gamma_1y(p_1)+\gamma_2y(p_2)$ are equal to $\alpha_0+\beta_0$. That's all.

Besides, $\dim\ker y=3$, not $4$.

Comment: You are correct, because apparently here $0^0=1$. But had I at least been correct if $0^0$ *were* equal to $0$? I mean, $y$ is defined such that $y(p)=p(0)$, and since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a vector space we would have $y(p_1+p_2)=y(p_3)=p_3(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, if $0^0=0$, you would be correct. But it is *never* $0$ in the context of polynomials.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It can be a bit confusing that $0^0$ can give different values depending on context.